# Collapse or Expandable Tree view using Tabris

Tags: tabris

I am trying to create an expandable / collapsible tree view (like Android's ExpandableListView widget) using Tabris Framework. The structure is as follow:

- Category 1
- Category 2

  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.2
  - Item 2.3
- Category 3

  - Item 3.1

Tabris has a Tree widget. With this, only Categories are displayed in the page. Child items can be opened in a new page only if one of the parent(Category) is selected. But I would like to display all in the same page like the structure above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Showing all items on the same "page" is currently no supported by the Tabris tree implementation. I would use a regular Composite with one column and perform the indention manually. Maybe with a GridLayout and the horizontalIdent property.